# DataGrid checkall not working

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

Hi have a Datagrid with rowCheckBoxes and an header checkbox for checking all.

The header checkbox bind a method in MainViewModel who will update the property of my model data to true. But the checkboxes are still unchecked.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="grdLignes" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding CmLignes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=hasLink, Mode=OneTime}" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <CheckBox Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.ToggleCheckAll}" CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="rowCheck" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=hasLink, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ref Mag" Binding="{Binding Path=refMag}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ref Fourn" Binding="{Binding Path=refFourn}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Désignation" Binding="{Binding Path=design}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantité" Binding="{Binding Path=qte, StringFormat=N2}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Fournisseur">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!--<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding FournList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=fourn}"/>-->
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=fournList}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=selectedFourn, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fourn princ" Binding="{Binding Path=fournPrinc}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pièce" Binding="{Binding Path=numPiece}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Then the MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ContremarqueRepository cmRepos;

    private ObservableCollection<Contremarque> cmLignes;
    public ObservableCollection<Contremarque> CmLignes
    {
        get { return cmLignes; }
        set
        {
            cmLignes = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CmLignes");
        }
    }
    public ICommand ToggleCheckAll { get; set; }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Collection<Contremarque> cms = cmRepos.getAll(doPiece);
        CmLignes = new ObservableCollection<Contremarque>(cms);

        ToggleCheckAll = new Command(ActionToggleCheckAll);
    }

    private void ActionToggleCheckAll(object param)
    {
        bool isChecked = (bool)param;
        if (isChecked)
        {
            foreach (Contremarque contremarque in CmLignes)
            {
                contremarque.hasLink = true;
            }
        }

        OnPropertyChanged("CmLignes");
    }
}
```

This is the Contremarque class:

```
public class Contremarque
{
    public bool hasLink { get; set; }
    public string refMag { get; set; }
    public string refFourn { get; set; }
    public string design { get; set; }
    public double qte { get; set; }
    public string fournPrinc { get; set; }
    public List<string> fournList { get; set; }
    public string selectedFourn { get; set; }
    public string numPiece { get; set; }

    public int dlNo;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string str = string.Empty;
        foreach (var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            str += string.Format("{0} = {1} ", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(this, null));
        }

        return str;
    }
}
```

The propertyChanged should update the state of my checkboxes isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `Contremarque` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and property `hasLink` should look like that:

```
public class Contremarque : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _hasLink;      
    public bool hasLink 
    {
        get { return _hasLink; }
        set
        {
            _hasLink= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: I added some details so you can see that the mainViewModel is already implementing INotifyPropertyChanged. All the collection values are updated but the checkboxes doesnt check

Comment: Understood. However it is not enought: you need also made your class that holds hasLink (Contremarque) view model too according to my example.

Comment: It still not working. hasLink is a property of Contremarque class. The Datagrid bind the Contremarque collection, so when the repository load the collection, Datagrid is properly populated. When data is modified, the collection is updated, but when i programmatically change the value of Contremarque::hasLink, nothing happens

Comment: because Contremarque doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
See my answer.

Comment: ho! i did not view your edited post ... It's working now. It is really strange that an entity implement InotifyPropertyChanged... But it's working so thank you!